# Why this opacity animation don't work?

Tags: css, animation, opacity

What's wrong with this animation?

```
.homepage-box:hover .shadow-layer
{
    opacity:0.70;
    -webkit-animation: opacity 5s;
    -moz-animation: opacity 5s;
}
```

in both chrome/firefox I can't see the fade in opacity...

Comment: What's your HTML code? Any other CSS?

Comment: how about a jsfiddle..

Comment: @techfoobar: no I haven't!

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: You want something like this [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/QDrNf/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the transition on the parent property as is (so not on :hover).

```
.homepage-box .shadow-layer {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5s ease-in-out;
}

.homepage-box:hover .shadow-layer {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: Yeah what's perfect ;) what if I want to animate `filter:alpha(opacity=30)` instead of opacity? Can I?

Comment: filter alpha is for IE6/7 and they don't allow transitions AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Change into `transition` not animation

Maybe this is what you want I guessed [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmD32/)